# Growing bacterial culture on gelatin

Tags: microbiology, experimental-design

I'm very new to experimental biology and don't know much about it. So, i was looking to grow some bacteria in petri dishes and looked up how to do it. Unfortunately, I'm finding it difficult to get my hands on the 'agar-agar' required to make the culture medium. So, is it possible to use any other alternative which would give the same results? Like for example regular gelatin?

My school lab teachers have also shown little to no interest in helping me with my project, so I'm on my own here. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try using agar powder also known as falooda powder which can substitute gelatine.it is used in Indian homes to make jelly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gelatin - actually this was used by microbiologists before agar came in use. That gelatin is more or less completely abandoned in this field tells quite a story, right?

Gelatin has the main disadvantage that it cannot be autoclaved together with the medium to sterilize it. Using it would need some experience and probably advanced techniques to which you have no access.
But there are some good news as well: Agar is also used as a geling agent when making food, and when you cannot find it in your local supermarket, Amazon can deliver it. You don't need much, around 15 gram/litre.

Comment: sadly Amazon doesn't ship products to my country :( (Bangladesh)

Comment: what other option would i have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gelatin. The problem you will find is that many more common organisms are able to break it down. Hence, it won't hold up very well. Depending what you put on it, it might work.

Comment: Can you add some references to your answer just to back it up a bit? Also, if there are any special preparation methods that should be followed or anything of that sort, please add that information and/or some reliable links to webpages with those instructions. PS... Welcome to Biology S.E., if you have any questions or concerns, please feel free to visit the Help Center, here https://biology.stackexchange.com/help :)